# Getting the error " TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'control'"

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the error:
TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'control'"

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DataStorageService, FieldConfig, ImportType } from '../../../../services/datastorage.service';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


import * as Papa from 'papaparse';
@Component({
  selector: 'field-analysis',
  templateUrl: './field-analysis.component.html'
})

export class FieldAnalysisComponent implements OnInit {

  fieldsGroup;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.fieldsGroup = new FormGroup({ fieldset: new FormArray([new FormControl(''), new FormControl('')]) });

  }

}
```

And the template looks like this.

```
<h2 >Field Definition</h2>
<form formGroup="fieldsGroup" novalidate>


<input *ngFor="let control of fieldsGroup.controls['fieldset'].controls" formControl="control">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You passed string `fieldsGroup` to **FormGroupDirective**. You should pass `FormGroup` instance instead:

```
[formGroup]="fieldsGroup"
```

And **FormControlDirective** also expects `FormControl` instance

```
[formControl]="control"
```